# Check if clients are alive

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I have a list of IP and ports of clients. I want to periodically update the list by checking if it is still possible to make a connection to each IP and port. How should I code it in python?

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
      self.ip = ip
      self.port = port



class Server():
    player_list = []

    def check_alive(self):  # TODO
       return False
```

Comment: What network protocol are the clients?  If it's http take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html

Comment: What have you tried so far?